# Is it legal to have cdata element inside doctype element

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, openxml, dtd

I want to know if it is legal to have CDATA element inside a doctype element in XML or OOXML ?If yes, then in which XML or OOXML ?

For e.g. :

```
<!DOCTYPE MSWord [<![CDATA[
    escaped
    data ]>] >
```

Is the above example correct .

Below is the complete XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE MSWord [<![CDATA[escaped
    data ]>] ><w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"><w:body><w:p w:rsidR="00D678AF" w:rsidRDefault="00DA46A9"><w:r w:rsidRPr="00DA46A9"><w:t>CDS Filter Test Data Element for ECMA XML</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:sectPr w:rsidR="00D678AF" w:rsidSect="00256063"><w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/><w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="720"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>
```

Comment: Adding https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-cdsection says 
[Definition: CDATA sections may occur anywhere character data may occur;

Comment: No, it's not correct because `<!DOCTYPE>` (which isn't an element) does not allow character data, see https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-doctype. CDATA is only for element allowed to contain `#PCDATA`.

Comment: Thanks, in that does it mean we can xml comments or PI inside doctype ? examples as below :
<!DOCTYPE MSWord [<?PITarget
     any
     string?>] >

<!DOCTYPE MSWord [<--XML COmments
     any
     string-->] >

Comment: Yes to both. Look at `[29]` in the provided pointer.  A `<!DOCTYPE` consists of element, attributes, entities, notation declarations + PI and comments.